# issue with regexp

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check if a string contain at least, a min, a maj and a number.

m2A is Ok

m2a is not Ok.

But when I try this:

```
$test = "m2A";
$regex = '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)$';
preg_match($regex,$test,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

I've got an error

> preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

I can't see what is wrong with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your current PHP script.  First, your regex string needs to be surrounded by delimiters, so use something like this:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$/
```

Notice also the second fix, which is that I add `.*` to your pattern, to consume anything, assuming that all three of your lookaheads have succeeded.

```
$test = "m2A";
$regex = '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*$/';
preg_match($regex,$test,$matches);
var_dump($matches);

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "m2A"
}
```

Comment: Thanks actually I already tried to add the '/' but I was getting an empty array. It's because I missed the star at the end actually thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP regex needs delimiters.
try adding '/' on both sides like so

```
$regex = '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)$/';
```